# Evaluate $\int \frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\left(\sqrt[3]{x}-1\right)\sqrt[6]{x^5}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How should I approach this?
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\left(\sqrt[3]{x}-1\right)\sqrt[6]{x^5}}\,dx$$
I intend to continue with the substitution method, however, I find it difficult to understand what to substitute.

I know that in these types of integrals must operate with the substitution:
$$x=t^n$$ where $n$ - least common multiple.

Can you show me how to solve it?

Comment: Where did the integral arise? The post could be improved, like most mathematical writing for a general audience, with additional motivation. Also, when you did the substitution, how far did you get? What actual problem did you encounter?

Comment: ya you can substitute $x=t^6$, it will work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x=t^6$. Then, $dx=6t^5dt$.
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\left(\sqrt[3]{x}-1\right)\sqrt[6]{x^5}}\,dx=\int \frac{(t^3+1)(6t^5)}{\left(t^2-1\right)t^5}\,dt=\int \frac{6(t^3+1)}{\left(t^2-1\right)}\,dt=\int \frac{6(t^2-t+1)}{\left(t-1\right)}\,dt=6\int \left(t+\frac{1}{\left(t-1\right)}\right)\,dt=6\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+\ln|t-1|\right)+c$$

Answer (score 2):

$x=t^6$ and $dx=6t^5 dt$ will solve the quesstion easily enough